# Sharing information in Django application

Tags: python, django

I have a very simple model that has data in it that I need to use in various places in my application:

```
class Setting(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    value = models.TextField()
```

I'd like to be able to load this information into a dictionary, then ship that data around my application so I don't have to make duplicate calls to the database. My attempt at doing so was wrapping the logic in a module like so (the `print` statement is there for debugging):

**my_settings.py**

```
from myapp import models
class Settings:
    __settings = {}

    def __init__(self):
        if(not self.__class__.__settings):
            print("===== Loading settings from table =====")
            qs = models.Setting.objects.all()
            for x in qs:
                self.__class__.__settings[x.name] = x.value

    def get(self, key, default=None):
        return self.__class__.__settings.get(key, default)

    def getint(self, key, default=0):
        return int(self.__class__.__settings.get(key, default))
```

Using this module would then look like the following:

```
from my_settings import Settings

# Down in some view somewhere...
settings = Settings()
data = settings.get("some_key")

...

# Now we might be in a helper function somewhere, but still in the
# same view context as above. Note that we should not have made
# a database round trip here; we're using our memory store instead.
settings = Settings()
data = settings.get("another_key")
```

This seems to work fine, but it has the drawback that the data is loaded once (and only once) at the initial instantiation. If any of the data in the settings database table should change, those changes won't be reflected in the corresponding dictionary held by this class.

Is there a better approach here? I don't mind having a single database query per request, but I also don't want to have to pass the dictionary around from function to function. I was hoping a module-level wrapper would get me the "singleton"-ness that I desire, but it's apparently caching things more aggressively than I thought it would.

Comment: Creating a middleware that update your `Settings.__settings` dict could be an option? This will update the settings once per request.

Answer (score 0):

I would just not worry about it and once you go into production either do blanket caching using [cachalot](http://django-cachalot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html) or write your own rough cache for just this model.